# How to Solve Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products' in 'field list' Base on this Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is not duplicate, so here's the issue.

Right now I'm working on a project and I'm experiencing something new, this project developed by some guy from a company which he didn't completed his job so I'm stuck with 1 problem in this app which it's getting this error when I'm trying to get a excel output.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products' in 'field list' (SQL: select `created_at`, `file_id`, `name`, `order`, `paid_price`, `phone`, `price`, `products`, `products_desc`, `products_order_desc`, `reagents`, `status`, `time_id`, `unpaid_price` from `customers`)"

I've experienced this before but not in a project like this, so here's the controller and models and blade file.

Before code, there are 3 button, 1 will search and get report, which it's working, other is cancel and export to excel, which i've got problem in excel, and getting this error in excel part.

Tables:

- products : id, name, desc, created_at, updated_at
- product_customer : id, product_id, customer_id, created_at, updated_at
- Reagents : id, name, desc, created_at, updated_at
- Reagents_customer : id, customer_id, reagent_id, created_at, updated_at
- customers : id, time_id, file_id, name, order, product_desc, product_order_desc, phone, status, price, paid_price, unpaid_price, created_at, updated_at

Customer.php

```
class Customer extends Model
{
protected $appends = ['jalali'];
protected $fillable=[
    'name','file_id','phone','quartz','artroz','available','order',
    'paid_price','unpaid_price','price','product_desc','order_desc',
    'products_order_desc','time_id','status','options',
];
// I've added products in fillable and didn't work.
protected $casts=[
    'order'=>'array'
];

public function reagents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Reagent', 'reagent_customer', 'customer_id', 'reagent_id');
}
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_customer', 'customer_id', 'product_id');
}
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_order_customer', 'customer_id', 'product_id');
}
}
```

Product.php

```
protected $fillable=[
    'name','desc','type'
];
```

Controller

```
class ReportController extends Controller
{
/**
 * show method for show report form
 */
public function show()
{
    return view('panel.report.report');
}
/**
 * show method for show report form
 */
public function p_show()
{
    // return toJalali(substr(1549202728000,0,10));
    // $v = verta();
    // return $v->timestamp(date(time()));
    // return dd($dt = $v->DateTime());
    // return   $c = Carbon::instance($v->DateTime());
    return view('panel.report.p_report');
}
/** 
 * handle paymanet report route
 */
public function handle_query_p(Request $request)
{
    $where=$this->c_query_builder();

    $start=Carbon::createFromTimestamp(substr($request->start_at,0,10))->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
    $end=Carbon::createFromTimestamp(substr($request->end_at,0,10))->hour(23)->minute(59)->second(59);
    return [
       'customers' =>Customer::with(['products','reagents'])->whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])->where($where)->get(),
       'row_headers'=>$this->get_items_generator(),
       'db_query'=>$where,
    ];
}

public function save_as_excel()
{   
    $header=request()->row_headers;
    $q=request()->db_query;
    if(!request()->has('db_query') || count(request()->db_query) ==0 )
    {
        $q=[];
    }
    $customer=Customer::with('products')->where($q)->get($header);
    \Excel::store(new CustomerExport($customer,$header), 'export.xlsx','public');
    return Storage::url('export.xlsx'); 
}
public function save_as_excel_p()
{   
    $header=request()->row_headers;
    $q=request()->db_query;
    $start=Carbon::createFromTimestamp(substr(request()->start_at,0,10))->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
    $end=Carbon::createFromTimestamp(substr(request()->end_at,0,10))->hour(23)->minute(59)->second(59);
    if(!request()->has('db_query') || count(request()->db_query) ==0 )
    {
        $q=[];
    }
    $customer=Customer::with('products')->whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])->where($q)->get($header);
    \Excel::store(new CustomerExport($customer,$header), 'export.xlsx','public');
    return Storage::url('export.xlsx'); 
}
public function handle_query(Request $request)
{
    $where=$this->c_query_builder();

    return [
       'customers' =>Customer::with(['products','reagents'])->where($where)->get(),
       'row_headers'=>$this->get_items_generator(),
       'db_query'=>$where,
    ];
}
public function get_items_generator()
{
    if(! request()->has('check_box'))
    {
        return [];
    }
    $items=[];
    foreach(request()->check_box as $key=>$item)
    {
        if($item!=false && $item!="false" )
        {
            $items[]=$key;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
public function c_query_builder()
{
    $params=$this->get_params();
    $query=[];
    foreach($params as $key=>$param)
    {
        $query[]=[$key,'like',"%".$param."%"];
    }
    return $query;
}
public function get_params()
{
    $table_fileds=\Schema::getColumnListing('customers');
    $data=request()->all();
    foreach($data as $key=>$item)
    {
        if(!in_array($key,$table_fileds) ||  $item==null)
        {
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
}
```

Here's the blade file which he used vue.js (problem is in save_excel) :

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        result:[],
        check_box:{
                created_at:true,
                file_id:true,
                name:true,
                order:true,
                paid_price:true,
                phone:true,
                price:true,
                products:true,
                products_desc:true,
                products_order_desc:true,
                reagents:true,
                status:true,
                time_id:true,
                unpaid_price:true,
                }
        ,
        name:null,
        created_at:null,
        file_id:null,
        order:null,
        paid_price:null,
        phone:null,
        price:null,
        products:null,
        products_desc:null,
        products_order_desc:null,
        reagents:null,
        status:null,
        time_id:null,
        unpaid_price:null,
        row_headers:null,
        e_time:null,
        s_time:null,
        db_query:null,
    },
    methods:{
        save_excel:function(){
            let self=this;
            let start_at=$('#start_at').val();
            let end_at=$('#end_at').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{route('report.save_as_excel_p')}}",
                data: {
                    _token:"{{csrf_token()}}",
                    row_headers            :self.row_headers,
                    db_query                :self.db_query,
                    'end_at'        :end_at,
                    'start_at'      :start_at,
                    },
                success: function (response) {

                    console.log(response);  
                    window.open(response);
                }
            });
        },
        query:function(){
            let self=this;
            let start_at=$('#start_at').val();
            let end_at=$('#end_at').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{route('report.handle_query_p')}}",
                data: {
                    _token:"{{csrf_token()}}",
                    name            :self.name,
                    created_at      :self.created_at,
                    file_id         :self.file_id,
                    order           :self.order,
                    paid_price      :self.paid_price,
                    phone           :self.phone,
                    price           :self.price,
                    products        :self.products,
                    products_desc   :self.products_desc,
                    products_order_desc       :self.products_order_desc,
                    reagents        :self.reagents,
                    status          :self.status,
                    time_id         :self.time_id,
                    unpaid_price    :self.unpaid_price,
                    check_box       :self.check_box,
                    'end_at'        :end_at,
                    'start_at'      :start_at,
                    },
                success: function (response) {
                  console.log(response);  
                  self.result=response.customers;
                  self.row_headers=response.row_headers;
                  self.db_query=response.db_query;
                }
            });
        }
    },
```

Search Response:

```
customers: [{id: 1, time_id: 1, file_id: "40001", name: "c1", order: "[]", product_desc: null,…}]
    0: {id: 1, time_id: 1, file_id: "40001", name: "c1", order: "[]", product_desc: null,…}
        created_at: "2019-02-28 11:13:31"
        file_id: "40001"
        id: 1
        jalali: "1397-12-09 11:13:31"
        name: "c1"
        order: "[]"
        paid_price: "20000"
        paid_price2: 0
        phone: "09167401933"
        price: "25000"
        product_desc: null
        products: [,…]
              0: {id: 2, name: "p2", desc: "p2", created_at: "2019-02-28 11:08:48",…}
        products_order_desc: null
        reagents: []
        status: "in_wait"
        time_id: 1
        unpaid_price: "5000"
        updated_at: "2019-02-28 11:13:31"
        db_query: []
```

I've added products in fillable and didn't work.

`save_excel` method in blade and in controller `save_as_excel()` are causing this problem.

Comment: Which is the method that causes this error?

Comment: @vivek_23 as i mention save_excel method in blade and in controller save_as_excel().

Comment: what's there in `$q` ? Also, what does the `Reagent` table have?

Comment: @vivek_23 Reagent Table added, and about $q as u can see in save_excel in blade file, save_excel posting query, which query in controller is = $q. if u want i can gave u remote control with team viewer or anydesk to check it.

Comment: Can you post the query that gets executed in the backend? Because your query has a where condition which I don't see in your error message. Also, please remove products from your fillable since you have written `// I've added products in fillable and didn't work.`.

Comment: which means you don't have column named as `products` in customers table

Comment: @vivek_23 query is top in Controller part sir. about products in fillabe, i was just mentioning about i've added, and didn't work, it's not in fillable for now.

Comment: @Manojkiran.A sir i've explained whole situation in top, products it's not in customer table.

Comment: @MohammadEskandari - Could you post a var_dump of the `$header=request()->row_headers;`. I belive the code is trying to get a `fild_name` that has not been loaded yet.

Comment: @MohammadEskandari I don't see the where condition in the query though which your controller method has. Also, I feel `products` is coming from front end which is getting directly attached to the fetched columns list.